# How can I check chess rules without a circular dependency?

Tags: chess

I'm writing a chess program in C++. I ran into an issue that I probably should have foreseen. The way the program finds all possible moves is by trying to move each piece to every square on the board. The function that does that is called `calculateAllPossibleMoves`. Each move is tested by cloning the game, and calling `move` on the piece being tested. The `move` function will throw an exception when a move is invalid. If no exception is thrown, then that move is valid, and it's added to the list of possible moves.

A move is not valid if it results in your king being in check. So I have a function that uses the find-all-possible moves function (let's call it `inCheck`) to see whether one of the opponent's pieces checks the king.

The problem is, the aforementioned `move` function relies on the `inCheck` function to find out whether the move results in check. `inCheck` uses `calculateAllPossibleMoves` to find all the moves that could potentially lead to the king. `calculateAllPossibleMoves` finds all the possible moves by simulating the move using the normal `move` function. This code runs forever because it's mutually recursive.

To try to fix it, what I did was introduce an edge case by passing in an integer. So when I call move, it decrements the integer and passes it along, and when move is called again, it is called with a lower number. That way, infinite recursion is not possible.

Still, the results seem to vary, and when I increase the number, the program takes a *very* long time to run. Is there a cleaner way to solve this problem?

Comment: Feel free to ask to see some code if that would help. I just didn't add any here because it's kind of long.

Comment: instead of trying to move each piece to "every possible square" how about just moving it to squares which are legal according to that piece's move rules? (e.g. bishop can only move on diagonals).

Comment: You shouldn't be using exceptions here, they are for exceptional conditions, not normal flow. It will make your code horribly slow as well as possibly being a maintenance problem

Comment: for the `inCheck` function you could go through the enemy pieces and see if any of them is attacking the king's square.  You should have a different function for "is attacking" than "can move" anyway, e.g. you don't need to consider castling, or pawns moving directly forward.

Comment: if you are just trying to prove one move then setting the counter to 2 should do it. 1 for your move, then 1 for the opponent.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I wanted to avoid coding the moving rules twice. So now, there is a `Bishop` class for example, and if move it somewhere, it checks to make sure it can legally make that move, otherwise it throws an exception.

Comment: @Hassan my advice would be not to use that design

Comment: @Calum You're right, that does work for the most part. I have some issues with it, but I'm not sure if it's another bug to be honest.

Comment: @MattMcNabb What would you recommend instead?

Comment: see my earlier comments :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb So what you're saying is I should have separate logic for finding if a king is in check?

Comment: Separate logic to see if a square is under attack, which you can apply to the king's square.

Comment: Your 'incheck' routine should not itself be calling 'incheck'. To understand why, imagine black's rook is pinned to his king; this does not mean white's king can move into check by that rook. For the purposes of 'incheck' checking the capture of white's king by black's (pinned) rook should be considered a legal move, even though it would itself result in check on the black king. You probably just need to pass a flag to the check routine to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have an abstract class ChessPiece inherited by all chess pieces, and 32 of those objects or something in an array of another class Game supporting a class BoardPosition, or something.

Then to list all moves, just go thru the active (not captured) pieces and for each cycle thru their moves (most are direction + number of squares). A move is valid if (1) there is no piece on the `way` and no same-color piece at the target position AND (2) no opponent's piece not taken by the tested move has in its possible moves the chance to capture your king in the updated board (because that's what check is -- mate just means that you cannot avoid the opponent taking your king)

Comment: Well I already coded all the moving rules. I do have an interface class (It's even called `ChessPiece`!) and all the other pieces inherit from it (`King`, `Queen`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is a `calculateIntersectingMoves` function which simply detects if any pieces have a valid move which intersects the square in question, and call it for check detection.

If `calculateAllPossibleMoves` is accurately named, it's horribly inefficient to use simply to see if there are any pieces which can reach a specific square; worse, it leads to the exact circularity you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I could do that. That would mean that I need to have some moving rules twice though. I tried to avoid that, but it may be the only way.

Comment: @Hassan I'd say a minor duplication of logic is probably worth it. Besides, with some optimizations, you could simply turn `calculateAllPossibleMoves` into a wrapper around `calculateIntersectingMoves` so you have your cake and eat it too.